# Android checkbox example

Tags: android, checkbox

I am trying to create an android application program..Is this possible to place the checkbox within the textview..if possible means tell some example..Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you try yourself to add checkbox into textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inflate `android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice` and you'll get a textview with a checkbox!

It's actually a `CheckedTextView`, so do it like

```
CheckedTextView whatever = (CheckedTextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(context);
                cb.setText("message");
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        if ( isChecked )
                        {
                            // perform logic
                        }

                    }

                });
```